# codeigniter echo record in controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

i am trying to echo the record in the controller from databases i basically want to send the mail but i am not able to echo record in the controller

controller codes

```
 function sendmail(){
$email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->load->model('m_login');
    $email=$this->m_login->search_mail_data($email);
}
```

model

```
function search_mail_data($email){
     $this->db->select('user_id, username, password');
    $this->db->from('login');
    $this->db->where('username', $email);
$query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() == 1) { 
        return $query->result(); //if data is true
    } else {
        return false; //if data is wrong
    }
```

Comment: actually what's your problem?

Comment: i want to echo the data and assign to a variable and then send that data to mail function problem is that i am not able to echo the data

Answer (score 1):

controller

```
function sendmail(){
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $this->load->model('m_login');
        $result=$this->m_login->search_mail_data($email);
    print_r($result); //print result
    }
```

Model

```
function search_mail_data($email=""){
         $this->db->select('user_id, username, password');
        $this->db->from('login');
        $this->db->where('username', $email);
    $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() == 1) { 
            return $query->result(); //if data is true
        } else {
            return false; //if data is wrong
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function sendmail(){
$email = $this->input->post('email');
    $data =  $this->load->model('m_login');
    var_dump($data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear friend try this code
In Controller

```
function sendmail(){
$email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->load->model('m_login');
    $email=$this->m_login->search_mail_data($email);
     foreach($email as $data)
       {
            echo $data->id;//echo whatever data you want
       } 
}
```